# Placing the blocks in their exact place

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, block, text

I am trying to create a title page. I create this sample with the help of this site. But i have a problem. In my sample my measurement is not real. When i print it the blocks are not in their place. For example last block is 26.5 cm below from the top of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}%türkçe karakter
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%türkçe karakter
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}%LoF paketi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parselines}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%times new roman
\usepackage{setspace}%satır aralığı
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{notoccite}%referans sırasını düzeltti.
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{%kağıt boyutları ve yazım alanı
    a4paper,
    left=40mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    }

\newcommand{\fromtop}[1]{%
  \dimexpr-1in-\topskip-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep+#1\relax
}
\newcommand{\fromleft}[1]{%
  \dimexpr-1in-\oddsidemargin+#1\relax
}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}

\begin{titlepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{3cm})
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \multirow{3}{*}{}
    &\textbf{T.C.}&\multirow{3}{*}{}\\
    &\textbf{FHDFGHFHDFH ÜNİVERSİTESİ}&\\
    &\textbf{FEN BİLİMLERİ ENSTİTÜSÜ}&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{6.5cm})
\centering
\textbf{DFHDFHDGHDFG ANABİLİM DALI}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{singlespacing}
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{9.5cm})
\centering
\textbf{SDFGDGGDSGFDSG\\
 TGFHGJJHDHFHD}
\end{textblock*}
\end{singlespacing}

\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{15cm})
\centering
\textbf{DOKTORA TEZİ}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{singlespacing}
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{16cm})
\centering
        \textbf{ASDGH}\\
        \textbf{2346445}
\end{textblock*}
\end{singlespacing}

\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{19.5cm})
\centering
        \textbf{Tezin Savunma Tarihi    : 00.00.0000}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{23cm})
\centering
        \textbf{Tez Danışmanı   : sdfgdgsd}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{singlespacing}
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-65mm}(\fromleft{4cm},\fromtop{26.5cm})
Bu Yüksek Lisans/Doktora Tez Çalışması sdgsdgsdgf Üniversitesi ………………’nolu Proje ile desteklenmiştir.
\end{textblock*}
\end{singlespacing}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the `\begin{singlespacing}` and `\end{singlespacing}` tags - they seem to be adding padding to the document that interferes with the `textblock`s.

If you want to have different line spacing for a certain part of your text, you can adjust it on the fly with `\\[10pt]` or `\\[-2pt]` or similar, at the end of lines.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. But now i can't print it. Tomorrow i print and measure spacing exaclty :)